# Implementing newsfeed using data from different social networks

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to implement a unified newsfeed using data from different social networks (Twitter, Facebook, Linkedin, etc.). Each Network again has different types of data, for example, I need to display twitter mentions, retweets, and even direct messages in the newsfeed.

I've created a `posts` table and for each type, I have a different table (eg. `twitter_mentions`, `retweets`). Right now, I have a column called `post_type` and `post_id` and based on `post_type` I can query the corresponding table. Now because of this strategy, I'll have to run different queries for each type.

Is there a better way to implement such unified newsfeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not bad.  Pretty standard for relational database and 3NF.  You can of course have only one table (aka `posts`) and keep adding more columns that are unique for each `post_type`, where they get filled in if relevant.  The problem with this is that in traditional relational databases, the number of columns are not suppose to change often.  Though with DB engines for MySQL like TokuDB (which uses fractal tree instead of B-tree) it is not a strain to add new columns (and indexes) as needed.

I would like to recommend a No-SQL DB for this type of setup.  In No-SQL databases the schema is intended to change often, or at least the tables (or table equivalents) are not tied down to a given schema.  You can see this in MongoDB, which stores its data as JSON, or BSON.  In MongoDB it is perfectly fine to store all the posts across different post-types into one collection.  There will be fields that are common across all post-types, and some fields will be unique to certain post types, and MongoDB is OK with that.  You can search against the common fields or the unique fields.